# how to create a polygon in PS Cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes

I have been troubled by this custom shape tool which was gone after I switched to CS6 or could I not Find it?
I have been looking for the Line Tool for hours and its custom shape tool but I could not find it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The Custom Shape tool and the Line tool are likely under the Rectangle tool. If you're using Adobe Photoshop CC (and I imagine it's the same on CS6) just click and hold on the Rectangle tool and a sub-menu should appear with both tools you're looking for.